# Unable to use skype4py in iron python

Tags: c#, python, .net, wpf, ironpython

I am trying to use skype4py in ironpython and getting following exception

```
An exception of type 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' occurred in                            Snippets.debug.scripting but was not handled in user code
Additional information: No module named dbus
```

the library works fine in simple python application but when I try to add it in iron python it gives me above exception .Following is my code

```
import wpf
import Skype4Py

from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication4.xaml')

       # Create an instance of the Skype class.
    skype = Skype4Py.Skype()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype4Py seems to rely on dbus which is not available for IronPython right now.

There are efforts to [implement the standard dbus python module using DBusSharp](http://www.ndesk.org/DBusSharp/Roadmap)

> IronPython API to implement current dbus-python API with managed D-Bus

but there is no indication if or when that will happen.

You could move from an IronPython + WPF app to CPython + *some other UI technology* or have a look at what dbus is used for in this context and see if you can work around it (which will probably not pan out as dbus seems to be the primary API).